# keep only ids that have all three values of the column Mode

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns, which looks like the following:

| Index | ID | Year | Code | Type | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 2018 | ABC | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 100 | 2019 | DEF | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 100 | 2019 | GHI | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 102 | 2018 | JKL | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 103 | 2019 | MNO | 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 103 | 2018 | PQR | 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 102 | 2019 | PQR | 3 | 2 |

I only want to keep ids that have rows against all the values for the column `Mode`. An example would look like this:

| Index | ID | Year | Code | Type | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 2018 | ABC | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 100 | 2019 | DEF | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 100 | 2019 | GHI | 3 | 3 |

I have already tried doing so by using the following code:

```
df = data.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: {1, 2, 3}.issubset(x['Mode']))
```

but this returns an empty result. Can someone help me here?
TIA

Comment: `issubset(set(x['Mode']))`?

Comment: mm if you 

>  keep ids that have the values 1,2 and 3 for the column 'Mode'.

, then you will keep the entire table, no?

Comment: Sorry, a typing error. What I mean is that I only want to keep ids which have all the values of column `Mode` in some or the other row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine (on pandas 1.3, python 3.9):

```
out = df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: {1,2,3}.issubset(x['Mode']))
```

Output:

```
   Index   ID  Year Code  Type  Mode
0      0  100  2018  ABC     1     1
1      1  100  2019  DEF     2     2
2      2  100  2019  GHI     3     3
```

Comment: I am doing this for approximately 35 million rows, and it takes forever to execute and the result is never processed. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
out = df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x : pd.Series([1,2,3]).isin(x['Mode']).all())
Out[9]: 
   Index   ID  Year Code  Type  Mode
0      0  100  2018  ABC     1     1
1      1  100  2019  DEF     2     2
2      2  100  2019  GHI     3     3
```

Comment: I am doing this for approximately 35 million rows, and it takes forever to execute and the result is never processed. Is there a solution for this? @BENY